Is creating button group with `<figure>` correct and comply with WCAG?
I am creating a button group with label like this:

The HTML code I am now writing:
<figure class="toggler-widget">
  <figcaption class="toggler-label">Sort By:</figcaption>
  <ul class="button-togglers">
    <li class="choice-selected">
      <button type="button" title="Sort by title" aria-label="Sort by title" aria-pressed="true"></button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="button" title="Sort by date" aria-label="Sort by date" aria-pressed="false"></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</figure>


Based on the description and example on MDN:

Usually a <figure> is an image, illustration, diagram, code snippet, etc.

Seems <figure> is used for text / image / diagram that having a description only.
I am now so confused that if I am using it right or if there is any better way to code this widget?

Is pressing the same button again switching between ascending and descending sorting?

@Andy No, they are just choice that either descending date or ascending title. Do you mean aria-pressed is using wrongly in this case?

It would have been not enough to communicate ascending/descending state. But since you ask: According to ARIA, a pressed state can be removed by clicking again. This is not the case here, but that’s probably not a practical issue.

@Andy Yep, I also wrote the state in the aria-label in my project, just simplified it before asking here haha.

@Andy For the pressed state, I actually followed primeVue to create it. It just sounds correct for me, or do you think using radiogroup, radio and aria-checked would be better?

No, it is not correct according to WCAG. The documentation you have quoted is correct but you misunderstood the explanation.
The very first quote is as follows:

The <figure> HTML element represents self-contained content, potentially with an optional caption, which is specified using the <figcaption> element. The figure, its caption, and its contents are referenced as a single unit.

Followed by this code example:


<figure>
  <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/elephant-660-480.jpg" alt="Elephant at sunset" />
  <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>



What you're doing is labeling the buttons not giving an optional caption to an image. As a matter of fact, the image is completely irrelevant for your toggler. The main function of the toggle are the buttons and the image is just decoration.
Since you can't use a label for 2 buttons you can either refer to aria-labelledby or aria-describedby.
Additionally, the correct list container for control elements is <menu>:


<span id="toggler-label">Sort By:</span>
<menu class="button-togglers">
  <li class="choice-selected">
    <button type="button" aria-describedby="toggler-label" aria-label="Sort by title" aria-pressed="true"></button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" aria-describedby="toggler-label" aria-label="Sort by date" aria-pressed="false"></button>
  </li>
</menu>




Great answer, I tend to forget about <menu>. Why the type="button"?

An alternative would be to name the menu: <menu aria-labelledby="toggler-label">, which would more reliably announce the groping title.

@Andy it is redundant - I just didn't removed it from the OP's code

I see, first heard of <menu> and will definitely implement it. Thanks for detail explanation!

@Andy Just my personal habit. As the default type of <button> is submit, which sometimes would like to be avoided. So I usually add it.

@tacoshy how is it redundant? The list doesn’t have any accessible name currently.

A button has by default the type button. Declaring type="button" as such is redundant. what has the type attribute of the button to do with the list? The menu makes the list already accessible. the buttons have a label and as such you do not specifically need to add any further information to the buttons for the screen readers.

@tacoshy A button's default type is "submit", not "button" https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type

@Sean that linked documentation refers to buttons within a form...

@tacoshy No, it refers to button in general. You can create an empty document with just a button element in it, inspect its properties using devtools, and see that the type property still defaults to "submit" even if it's not in a form.

I would recommend a different variation of tacoshy's answer. The issue with their approach is that adding aria-describedby to the buttons will cause screen readers to announce both the label and the description for each button. This means that screen reader users will hear "Sort by title, sort by" and "Sort by date, sort by" as they focus the buttons.
It's better to instead associate the "sort by" span with the <menu> element itself. This will provide context to what that menu is, while also avoiding announcing "sort by" multiple times for the same element.


<span id="sort-label">Sort By:</span>
<menu aria-labelledby='sort-label'>
  <li><button type="button" aria-label="Sort by title" aria-pressed="true"></button></li>
  <li><button type="button" aria-label="Sort by date" aria-pressed="false"></button></li>
</menu>




Indeed, that should be better for a screen reader
